# Fixed tr height, with unknown multiline div inside

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with rows that need to be constant height. (Also width--but `table-layout:fixed` seems to solve this.) The `<tr>`s have `<div>`s inside them, and they need to occupy 100% of the height of their cells. If the contents of the `<div>` goes over, there needs to be a scrollbar. If it goes under, it still needs to occupy the full row.

Here's some minimal code:

```
<table border="1" width="200" style="table-layout:fixed;"><tbody>
    <tr style="height:100px;">
        <td>
            <div style="height:100%; overflow:scroll; background-color:#cdf;">
                abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefg<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100px;">
        <td>
            <div style="height:100%; overflow:scroll; background-color:#fcc;">
                abc
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

But this isn't working in either case: if the contents of the `<div>` are too long, it grows the cell and doesn't bother to use the scrollbar. If the contents are too short, it doesn't occupy the whole row. Any thoughts on a browser-independent way to establish a `<tr>` as having a single, hard-set size? Also, please keep in mind that the actual contents of the `<div>`s are dynamic, and I don't know them ahead of time. Thanks.

Comment: Please love yourself and use a style sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put `style="height:100px;"` on your `<td>` tags:

```
<table border="1" width="200" style="table-layout:fixed;"><tbody>
<tr >
    <td style="height:100px;">
        <div style="height:100%; overflow:scroll; background-color:#cdf;">
            abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefg<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr >
    <td style="height:100px;">
        <div style="height:100%; overflow:scroll; background-color:#fcc;">
            abc
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This works. But do you know why it has to be a pixel amount? When I try to use percentages, it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing beyond this is really needed. `table-layout: fixed;` is required to have fixed table width.

```css
table{
  width: 200px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr:nth-child(1){
  background-color: #cdf;
}
tr:nth-child(2){
  background-color: #fcc;
}
table div{
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table border="1"><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>              abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefgasdasdasdasd<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc<br/>abc
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
               abc
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: This gets the small example working, but not the large one for me. (And yes, stylesheets make it prettier. I was trying to make minimal code.)

Comment: @AdamSmith What do you mean "big example"?

Comment: There were 2 cells--one with too much text for the box, one with too little. The boxes need to be of constant size.

Comment: Just change max-height to height... @AdamSmith Sometimes the easiest answer isn’t the best